# Disable DOMDocument to format the code

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

How to make DomDocument not to insert p tags inside the content?

I use this code:

```
$content = 'http://google.com';

// New DOM
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->recover = false;
@$document->loadHTML( $content );
$content = $document->saveHTML();

print_r( $content );
```

Does not help, the output is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>http://google.com</p></body></html>
```

I want it to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>http://google.com</body></html>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe it is possible but it would result in invalid HTML. You'd have to grab the <p> tag and replace it with its contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = 'http://google.com';

// New DOM
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->recover = false;
@$document->loadHTML( $content );

// Copy contents of <p> to <body>
$body = $document->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0);
$p = $document->getElementsByTagName("p")->item(0);
foreach ($p->childNodes as $e) {
    $body->appendChild($e);
}
$body->removeChild($p);
// Resume OP's code

$content = $document->saveHTML();

print_r( $content );
```